# Using the --perf-basic-prof option with Node on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, v8

I'm trying to use the '--perf-basic-prof' option on node, which was introduced in node v0.11.13.  However, when I try:

```
node --perf-basic-prof myscript.js
```

I get:

```
#
# Fatal error in ..\..\src\log.cc, line 267
# CHECK_NE(perf_output_handle_, NULL) failed
#   Value: 00000000
#
```

**Does this just not work on Windows?  Am I using it wrong?**

- Windows 7 64bit
- node v0.11.14
- Running as administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Linux specific flag: it generates output used for the `perf` tool.

Comment: Is there any way to produce something similar under windows?

Comment: @UpTheCreek For imprecise profiles you can use builtin sampling profiler enabled through `--prof`. Check out npm package `tick` for instructions. The only *real* alternative to `perf` that is available on Windows is Intel VTune. However it is not free and you would need to rebuild node from the source with some changes to V8's GYP files as right now it seems only `d8` compilation target respects `v8_enable_vtunejit`.